# .... (bunch of dots) on elements of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have links in a column of a data frame in pandas. whenever I try to iterate through that column(links) and get some text data the following happens.
suppose df is the data frame

```
    for i in df:
    for line in urllib.request.urlopen(i):
        decoded_line = line.decode("utf-8")
        print(decoded_line)
```

if I run the above code, it shows an error.
Then When I printed that column, I saw those column elements (links) end with a bunch of dots...
After searching a little I did,

```
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100
```

And it worked fine.

But I am curious how changing the " display column width " resolves my issue.

As far as I understood, when I was working with    `pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 50`     the 'i' in for loop was taking some portion of the links with a bunch of dots in the end(why? How display width changes values actually taken by 'i'), and now when I change the display column width to 100    `pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100`    it is taking the whole link.  But why?

And is pd.options.display.max_colwidth changes only the display col-width or it has aslo something to do with the actual value?

Please help
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The length of `i` is larger than `50` but less than `100`. For an unlimited length, use `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)`.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, not that,  I suppose. I am unable to explain to you the question.